# jQuery selector for dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery

I have the following html snippet:

```
<div id="contentX"><h1>MyHeading1</h1></div>
```

I could select with jQuery snippet syccessfully with the following:

```
console.log($('#contentX h1'));
```

The output is

```
[<h1>​MyHeading1​</h1>​]
```

However, it did **not** work when I dynamically loaded the contents. For example,

html code snippet:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

jQuery code snippet:

```
$('#content').load('foo.html')); // the content is loaded correctly with <h1> tag
```

jQuery code snippet does **not** work:

```
console.log($('#content h1')); // it returns []. I was expecting to return something.
```

I am wondering if this is a similar behavior like event binding: .click() vs .live().

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And what did `foo.html` contain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `load` function is asynchronous, meaning it starts the load and then it carries on in the background and then continues to execute the rest of your script.

It does not wait for the `load` to complete first.

You can attach a function to the `load` call to tell jQuery to do it once the load is complete.
Here is an example:

```
$('#content').load('foo.html', function() {     
    console.log($('#content h1'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#content').load('foo.html', function () {
    console.log($('#content h1'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Load is one of jQuery's shorthand AJAX methods, and same as animation functions and others, it doesn't wait until it finishes loading the external file (foo.html) in order to run. Try putting the console.log (or whatever you want there) as a callback:

```
(...).load([url], function() {
  console.log("whatever");
}
```

You can also use the callback to catch errors when trying to fetch the page:

```
(...).load([url], function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    alert("Well, that didn't really work, here's the reason why:" + xhr.statusText);
  }
}
```

Refer to the .load page on jQuery's API to dig further: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Hope this works for you